# How to dynamically hide/show a DIV area in a custom row formatter

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a custom row formatter to display Q&A information in a list. I'd like for the display to show on Row 1 the Q, and Row 2 the A.

But - I want the initial view to not display any of the "A"s unless an element of Row 1 has been clicked.

Example below:

**Q: How do I sort on a column in SharePoint.  >>**

When >> is clicked

**Q: How do I sort on a column in a SharePoint library?  >>**

**A: To sort - click the dropdown arrow next to the column name.**

If you can provide a code snippet that triggers on click and changes the display mode from none to block, and block to none, that'd be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change list view settings and group by on question column, then apply group view formatting as given in below sample:

[image]

**Sample Reference**: [faq-accordion](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/blob/master/view-samples/faq-accordion/faq-accordion.json)

Comment: Hi @VASoftball5, did you try above solution?

Comment: Ganesh - thanks for the post. This is a viable solution to the issue!  Just needed to think about the problem in an different way.

Comment: You're welcome @VASoftball5. Glad it helped you!